# Is this the correct way to assign memory to heap and deallocate it in C? Did I do this right?

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, iteration

I've stumbled upon an interesting problem while preparing for my exam, and I'm unsure as to whether I've solved it or not. I will provide the text of the problem, as well as my code:

[image]

```
void charAlloc(){
char *arrPtr;
arrPtr = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
int i;
for (i=0; i<101; i++){
    if (*(arrPtr+i) % 5 == 0){
        *(arrPtr + i) = 'a';
    }
    if (*(arrPtr+i) % 3 && *(arrPtr+i) % 7 != 0 && *(arrPtr+i) / 2 != 0){
        *(arrPtr+i) = 'b';
    }
    else{
        *(arrPtr+i) = 'c';
    }
}
free(arrPtr);
}
```

Since it's a void function there isn't really a way to check if it's doing what it's supposed to in this case, so I thought I'd ask here. I do sometimes struggle with pointers so it's quite possible I maybe messed up something there. There's no errors or warnings in the compiler.

Comment: So, the funny thing that this function could be very well optimized out completely if written properly (i.e. not leaking memory).

Comment: I don't see any immediate mistakes, but I recommend using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) when checking for memory issues, it is a very useful tool.

Comment: `i<101` is the immediate mistake. It will iterate `101` times

Comment: Should index 15 be `a` or `b`? if `a` you missed the `else` before the long `if`.

Comment: Also you are checking the divisibility of the *value* at the pointed location (which is uninitialized), not the index.

Comment: Don't check the remainder of the data in the allocated array, its garbage values. You need to check if i%5 and same for the others

Comment: Ah I was just thinking about that, you're right. I didn't start iterating from 1, in which case $i<101$ would be fine, but instead from a zero. Do you think that my method of iterating through "indexes" is okay?

Comment: No, it won't be fine, unless you offset it by one when indexing. Indexing should start with zero.

Comment: @mch good point, I completely overlooked that

Comment: In any case `*(arrPtr+i)` is fully equivalent to `arrPtr[i]`, which is way more readable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. would the problem of iterating through value rather than index be solved by simply removing the *? Should I maybe define an array instead, and then use a pointer to point to the array?

Comment: You need to *test* `i`, but *assign* `*(arrPtr+i)`

Comment: I think I understand now. I've replaced the if conditions with i % 5 == 0 etc. like @JakeKorman and EugeneSh. said, it makes a lot more sense now. Thank you

Comment: In addition to testing the wrong value, the arithmetic tests for condition 'b' are completely wrong. It should be something like `i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 != 0 && i % 2 != 0` ("not an even number" means "not divisible by 2").

Comment: @IanAbbott goodness, I've just noticed that... It doesn't say anything after % 3, just goes to the next condition... Not only that, but the check for divisibility by 2 is also wrong. Thank you for pointing that out, I'm so clumsy today. Is it possible to close a question and flag a comment as the answer?

Comment: @emcosokic No, a comment cannot be flagged as an answer. Besides, different problems have been pointed out in different comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has been answered in the comments. Firstly, instead of going through the loop for `101` times, it should iterate `100` times: `for(i=0; i<100; i++)`.

The next mistake was in the `if` branches within the loop. What `*(arrPtr+i)` does is it selects the value stored at that address.
This is not the value of the index, but rather a garbage value appointed to the heap.

What I should've done instead is checked for the values of `i`, and assign the values given in the problem to `*(arrPtr+i)`.

There was another mistake pointed out within the `if` branches. In the second `if` conditional, for assigning value 'b' to certain indexes, the testing statements are incorrect. They stated:

---

`if (*(arrPtr+i) % 3 && *(arrPtr+i) % 7 != 0 && *(arrPtr+i) / 2 != 0)`

Which is incorrect in several parts. The first condition is not even finished, it should say `if (*(arrPtr+i) % 3 == 0`, and the last condition does not check properly if the number is divisible by two. `*(arrPtr+i) % 2 != 0` would be the proper way to do that.

With all this combined, the final result should be something like this:

```
void charAlloc(){
     char *arrPtr;
     arrPtr = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
     int i;
     for (i=0; i<100; i++){
         if (i % 5 == 0){
            *(arrPtr+i) = 'a';}
         else if (i % 3 == 0 && (i % 7 != 0) && (i % 2 !=0)){
             *(arrPtr+i) = 'b';}
         else {
             *(arrPtr+i) = 'c';}
     }
     free(arrPtr);
     }
```

I'd like to thank all the commenters for helping me understand this problem and I hope other programmers with issues similar to mine can find this useful.